# Cloudera: upload a File in the HDFS Exception

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I use a MAC OS X Yosemite with a VM cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.2-0-virtualbox. When I type "hdfs dfs -put testfile.txt" to put a TEXT FILE into HDFS I get a **DataStreamer Exception**. I notice that the main problem is that the number of nodes that I have is null. I copy here below the complete error message and I would like to know how should I do to solve this.

```
> WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer
> Exceptionorg.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException):
> File /user/cloudera/testfile.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to
> 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 0 datanode(s)
> running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation. at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1541)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3286)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:667)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:212)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:483)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040) at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source) at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
> org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.addBlock(Unknown Source) at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1544)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1361)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:600)put:
> File /user/cloudera/testfile.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to
> 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 0 datanode(s)
> running and no node(s) are excluded in this
> operation.[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hdfs dfs -put testfile.txt15/10/18
> 03:51:51 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer
> Exceptionorg.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException):
> File /user/cloudera/testfile.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to
> 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 0 datanode(s)
> running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation. at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1541)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3286)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:667)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:212)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:483)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040) at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
> at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399) at
> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source) at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
> org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.addBlock(Unknown Source) at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1544)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1361)
> at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:600)put:
> File /user/cloudera/testfile.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to
> 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1). There are 0 datanode(s)
> running and no node(s) are excluded in this
> operation.[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Stop Hadoop services as describe in** [Stopping Services](http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_27_3.html)

```
for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop*` ; do sudo service $x stop ; done
```

**2. Remove all files from** **`/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/`**

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/
```

**3. Format Namenode**

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs namenode -format

Note: Answer with a capital Y

Note: Data is lost during format process.
```

**4. Start Hadoop Services**

```
for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop*` ; do sudo service $x start ; done
```

**5. Ensure that your system is not running on low diskspace. You can also confirm this if there is any WARNING about low diskspace in Log files.**

**6. Create the /tmp Directory**

```
Remove the old /tmp if it exists:
    $ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -rm -r /tmp

Create a new /tmp directory and set permissions:

    $ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp 
    $ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 1777 /tmp
```

**7. Create User Directories:**

```
$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -mkdir /user/<user> 
$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown <user> /user/<user>

where <user> is the Linux username
```

Comment: Hi @Vinkal, I've updated. Is this right? Or have yet to do something?

Comment: After accepting an answer, to upvote an answer, click on the 'up triangle' before the answer. When you move mouse cursor on 'up triangle', it shows "This answer is useful', Ensure that you click on 'up triangle' to vote as 'This answer is useful'. please follow this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Hi @Vinkal thanks for the explanation. I have made it!  :)