# Cannot write to HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to HDFS. When I try to write in HDFS file I received the following:

> [WARN] org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - DataStreamer Exception >java.io.IOException: Unable to create new block]. The response code is 200,

but when read file content this is null. Here is my code:

```
public void writeFile(FileSystem fs, String destination) throws IOException {

    Path workingDir = fs.getWorkingDirectory();
    Path newFilePath = new Path("/" + destination);
    newFilePath = Path.mergePaths(workingDir, newFilePath);

    FsPermission fsPermission = new FsPermission(FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL, FsAction.ALL);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        sb.append("Data");
        sb.append(i);
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    byte[] byt = sb.toString().getBytes();

    FSDataOutputStream fsOutStream = null;
    try {
        fsOutStream = fs.create(fs, newFilePath, fsPermission);

        fsOutStream.write(byt);

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.error("Error while creating file in Hdfs",e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fsOutStream != null) {
                fsOutStream.close();
            }
        }catch(Throwable e) {
                log.error("Error while closing FSDataOutputStream", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions is welcome. Thank you in advance!

Comment: please post complete stacktrace

Comment: Have a look at : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-101. Is your datanode up and running?

Comment: my datanodes are up and  running and the hadoop cluster is started

Comment: also I have 200GB free space

Comment: see if this SO link helps, it also talks about DataStreamer Exception : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199590/cloudera-upload-a-file-in-the-hdfs-exception/33200607#33200607

Comment: Thank you, but this link don't help me. I appreciate